# Why isn't my registered sidebar showing up in the admin?

Tags: sidebar, register-sidebar

I'm using sidebars in my mega menu drop downs to let the admin add widgets specific areas of the menu:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="sub-menu-item first">
        <ul>
            <li class="menu-col"><?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'submenu1-1' ) ) : ?><?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?></li>
            <li class="menu-col"><?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'submenu1-2' ) ) : ?><?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?></li>
            <li class="menu-col"><?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'submenu1-3' ) ) : ?><?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?></li>
            <li class="menu-col"><?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'submenu1-4' ) ) : ?><?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sub-menu-item second">
        <ul>
            <li class="menu-col"><?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'submenu2-1' ) ) : ?><?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?></li>
            <li class="menu-col"><?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'submenu2-2' ) ) : ?><?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?></li>
            <li class="menu-col"><?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'submenu2-3' ) ) : ?><?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?></li>
            <li class="menu-col"><?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'submenu2-4' ) ) : ?><?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

in my functions.php:

```
function my_widgets_init() {
/**
 * menu widget areas
 **/
 //area 1
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'First Menu Item - First Column', 'cfhof' ),
    'id'            => 'submenu1-1',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<p class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</p>',
) );
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'First Menu Item - Second Column', 'cfhof' ),
    'id'            => 'submenu1-2',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<p class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</p>',
) );
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'First Menu Item - Third Column', 'cfhof' ),
    'id'            => 'submenu1-3',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<p class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</p>',
) );
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'First Menu Item - Fourth Column', 'cfhof' ),
    'id'            => 'submenu1-4',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<p class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</p>',
) );

//area 2
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'Second Menu Item - First Column', 'cfhof' ),
    'id'            => 'submenu2-1',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<p class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</p>',
) );
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'Second Menu Item - Second Column', 'cfhof' ),
    'id'            => 'submenu2-2',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<p class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</p>',
) );
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'Second Menu Item - Third Column', 'cfhof' ),
    'id'            => 'submenu2-3',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<p class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</p>',
) );
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'Second Menu Item - Fourth Column', 'cfhof' ),
    'id'            => 'submenu2-4',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<p class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</p>',
) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_widgets_init' );
```

the first set shows up but not the second.

Comment: I see all of your sidebars when I test this.

Comment: I think it's server side. The files are controlled by SVN. My files are pushing up fine. I checked them out in a different folder any functions.php and header.php file are correct.